# Many-to-many controller on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to do a many-check-box with a many-to-many association. 
I have tree models 
Empresa:

```
class Empresa < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :empresa_pagamento
  has_many :formas_pagamentos, :through =>  :empresa_pagamento
  has_one :tipo_restaurante
  has_many :produtos
end
```

Forma Pagamento

```
class FormaPagamento < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :empresa_pagamento
  has_many :empresas, :through => :empresa_pagamento
end
```

Empresa Pagamento

```
class EmpresaPagamento < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :empresa
  belongs_to :forma_pagamento  
end
```

On my empresa_controller I have my params

```
def empresa_params
  params.require(:empresa).permit(:nome, :descricao, :cnpj, :razao_social,:formas_pagamentos, :tipo_restaurante)
end
```

When i try to save i do :

```
def create
  @empresa = Empresa.new(empresa_params)    

  respond_to do |format|
    if @empresa.save
      @empresa.formas_pagamentos.each do |forma_pagamento|
        empresa_pagamento = EmpresaPagamento.new
        empresa_pagamento.forma_pagamento = FormaPagamento.find(forma_pagamento)
        empresa_pagamento.empresa = @empresa
        empresa_pagamento.save
      end      
      format.html { redirect_to @empresa, notice: 'Empresa was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @empresa }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @empresa.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

on my _form i have

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :formas_pagamentos %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:formas_pagamentos, FormaPagamento.all, :id, :nome,{:prompt => "Selecione"}, {:multiple => true}) %>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using has_and_belongs_to_many which will automatically use the join table?

Comment: the hibernate on JSF don't work well with the join_table automatic and the first example on the rails guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) shows like that ...but don't show how the controller should work with associations.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the bug you are seeing? What do you observe? what do you expect instead?

Comment: When you submit the form - look at the server-log and copy/paste the params that arrive, and any error messages just after. Often if there is an unexpected field-name, it will show up as a not-permitted field in the server log.

Comment: Fix formating to improve readability

Comment: So ... tryed the solution from @DavidHoelzer then in the rails console the formas_pagamentos.empresas make the inner join but when i try the reverse i get NameError: uninitialized constant Empresa::FormasPagamento. and it's true the constant FormasPagamento does't exist because the correct it's the FormaPagamento.